# Is there any other way to calculate X value in coords of other coord system?

Tags: algorithm, coordinates

Sorry, for weird topic name, but I don't know how else to name it.
[image]

The problem is.. I have a zedgraph control. There is some lines drawn inside.

I have the coords of left border of chart area and right border of chart area.

I draw vertical lines as PictureBoxes over zedgraph control, so they moves in different coords. This vertical lines can be moved to left and right.

That way I trying to get X value in coords of XAxis:

```
public double Get_X_InContextOfChart(int left_coord_of_border) //Left of vertical line
{
    //zed_graph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min is minimal X value shown on XAxis
    //zed_graph.GraphPane.Chart.Rect.Left is Left of YAxis
    //Same for else if, aside of using Right and maximum X at right
    if (zed_graph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min != 0) //to avoid division by zero
        return (left_coord_of_border * zed_graph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min) / zed_graph.GraphPane.Chart.Rect.Left;
    else if (zed_graph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max != 0)
        return (left_coord_of_border * zed_graph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max) / zed_graph.GraphPane.Chart.Rect.Right;

    return double.NaN;
}
```

This code calculate X fine as long as **else if** used, but in my example it calculate something wrong.

I hope someone understand this.

Updated with new code:

```
public double Get_X_InContextOfChart(int left_coord_of_border)
{
   double scale_left = zed_graph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min;
   double scale_right = zed_graph.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max;
   double graph_width = zed_graph.GraphPane.Chart.Rect.Width;
   double x = left_coord_of_border;

   return scale_left + (scale_right - scale_left) / graph_width * x;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scale_left = -0.1
scale_right = 0.9
graph_width = 540 // pixels
x = 190           // pixels

scale_x = scale_left + (scale_right - scale_left) / graph_width * x  // 0.25
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, it still calculate something wrong... Please, look update in my question

Comment: Fixed it by doing this double x = left_coord_of_border - zed_graph.GraphPane.Chart.Rect.Left; That was the root of all my problems... Thank you for basic idea

Comment: @Kosmos - `double x = left_coord_of_border - 56;`